# Is there a tool, preferably an Eclipse plugin, to check if accessor and mutator methods are in the JavaBean format?

Tags: java, eclipse, javabeans

It appears that Eclipse generates accessor and mutator methods in JavaBean format. However, through refactoring (both manual and using Eclipse's refactoring tool), sometimes the method names and the name of the instance variable they correspond to become out of sync. Is there a tool that checks and identifies methods that are not in the appropriate JavaBean format for the variable that they modify or return? I'm currently using Eclipse with CodePro Analytix and I don't see this functionality.

Comment: Nothing in the JavaBean conventions requires that getters and setters match with the field they access. Nothing even mandates that such a field exists. What's important is the name of the methods. The field name constitutes an implementation detail.

Comment: It might not be part of the formal convention, but when dealing with accessors and mutators that directly access instance variables, it's something that I've always seen.

Comment: Technically a Java Bean property is defined by the getter and/or setter only, there is no need for an instance variable at all. A property can e.g. computed at access time. So to check for correct properties a tool should not look at any variables that are accessed by methods with the property name pattern. In practice, of course, the private variable/getter/setter pattern is so common that tools like the already mentioned Checkstyle can check this. When using the advanced features of Eclipse's rename refactoring you can avoid them to be out of sync automatically.

Comment: @his That would work if everyone used Eclipse and the refactoring tool. That's not necessarily the case, and projects get out of sync.

Comment: Hm, I interpreted your text "However, through refactoring (both manual and using Eclipse's refactoring tool), sometimes the method names and the name of the instance variable they correspond to become out of sync." as if even with Eclipse's refactoring tools the sync could break - which can happen, when the advanced features are not used.

Comment: @his That may be true. I know that not every developer is or has been as careful as I am, and I'm tying to detect problems regardless of what causes it.

Comment: There is a way to emulate C#'s setter and getter generation in Java, with Lombok. It is really nice but honestly I wouldn't use it in big teams with different tools used as the code needs treatment by an APT to work correctly. Sorry, it sounds to me that this will not be the right tool for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may find what you want with the [CheckStyle](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) plugin.
Here is how to [setup](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/basic_setup_project.html) your project

Answer (score 0):

PMD also would work http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/index.html#JavaBeans. For Eclipse plugin config : http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/integrations.html#eclipse.

Comment: I don't see a rule that does what I want. Could you specifically identify the one that you think will help?

Comment: `BeanMembersShouldSerialize` : Accessor methods should follow the Java naming conventions.